# Retrieve Trigger.newMap Values In After Update Context

Tags: apex, trigger

I have the following Trigger, Class & Unit Test

```
trigger WE_MasterOpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (
    before insert, after insert, 
    before update, after update, 
    before delete, after delete)
{    
    if (Trigger.IsAfter) {
        if (Trigger.isInsert) {
            // class needs to execute in After context so that values are still populated when 
            // an Opportunity is created through Lead conversion
            WE_OppUpdates oppPreparation = new WE_OppUpdates(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap);
            oppPreparation.updateOpportunities();
        } 
        if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
            WE_OppUpdates oppPreparation = new WE_OppUpdates(Trigger.oldMap,Trigger.newMap);
            oppPreparation.updateOpportunities();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class WE_OppUpdates {

    // variables
    Map<Id, Opportunity> oldOpps;
    Map<Id, Opportunity> newOpps;
    Date cd;
    Opportunity oldOpp;
    List<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();

    // constructor
    public WE_OppUpdates(
        Map<Id, Opportunity> oldTriggerOpps, 
        Map<Id, Opportunity> newTriggerOpps) {
            oldOpps = oldTriggerOpps;
            newOpps = newTriggerOpps;
        }

    public void updateOpportunities() {

                if (Trigger.isInsert){

                    List<Opportunity> insertedOpps = [SELECT Id, CloseDate, Ramp_Profile__c FROM Opportunity
                                                       WHERE Id IN :newOpps.keySet()];

                    for (Opportunity o : insertedOpps){

                            cd = o.CloseDate;

                            if (o.Ramp_Profile__c == 'Immediate'){
                                o.Implementation_Revenue__c = cd.addDays(15);
                                o.Revenue_Commencement__c = o.Implementation_Revenue__c.addMonths(1).toStartOfMonth();
                                // etc
                            } else if (o.Ramp_Profile__c == 'Standard'){
                                // set different values 
                            } 
                    }
                    update oppsToUpdate;
                }

                if (Trigger.isUpdate){

                    List<Opportunity> updatedOpps = [SELECT Id, RecordTypeId, CloseDate, Ramp_Profile__c FROM Opportunity
                                                      WHERE Id IN :newOpps.keySet()];

                    for (Opportunity o : updatedOpps){

                            cd = o.CloseDate;

                            Opportunity oldOpp = oldOpps.get(o.Id);

                            system.debug('oldOpp Ramp Profile is ' + oldOpp.Ramp_Profile__c);
                            system.debug('newOpp Ramp Profile is ' + o.Ramp_Profile__c);
                            system.debug('oldOpp Close Date is ' + oldOpp.CloseDate);
                            system.debug('newOpp Close Date is ' + o.CloseDate);

                            if (oldOpp.CloseDate != o.CloseDate
                                ||
                                oldOpp.Ramp_Profile__c != o.Ramp_Profile__c){
                                    if (o.Ramp_Profile__c == 'Immediate'){
                                        o.Implementation_Revenue__c = cd.addDays(15);
                                        }
                                        oppsToUpdate.add(o);

                                    } else if (o.Ramp_Profile__c == 'Medium'){
                                        // set different values
                                    }
                            } 
                    }
                    update oppsToUpdate;
    }
}
```

---

```
@isTest
public class WE_OppUpdatesTest{

    @testSetup
    static void dataSetup() {

            List<Opportunity> opportunities1 = WE_TestDataUtility.createOpportunities(
                25,                                 // noOpps
                '<*>',                              // identifier
                date.today().addMonths(1),          // closeDate
                'Standard');                        // rampProfile

            insert Opportunities1;
    }

    static testMethod void testOppUpdates(){

        List <Opportunity> opportunities = [SELECT Id,RecordTypeId,Name,CloseDate,Ramp_Profile__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Name LIKE '%<*>%'];

        Test.startTest();

        for(Opportunity o : opportunities){
            o.CloseDate = o.CloseDate.addmonths(1);
            o.Ramp_Profile__c = 'Immediate';

        }
        update opportunities;
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

When I run the test my debug lines in the `isUpdate` section show that the values for the `Ramp_Profile__c` & `CloseDate` fields are unchanged.

My understanding is that the two maps should contain the old & new values so perhaps I'm not passing the values through to my Class correctly or is this issue occurring because of my SOQL query or something else?

Comment: why not use a before insert/update to do this and avoid the whole query and DML sequence?

Comment: @crop1645 In my org we don't execute Before Triggers on Lead conversion & this code needs to execute whenever a new Opportunity is created - including as part of a Lead's conversion. Changing the setting would activate all Validation Rules & required fields during Lead conversion so this is the better alternative.

Comment: @AlexS Correct me if I'm wrong, but it appears that your code should blow up instead of working correctly. It should be after insert, before update. In the after insert trigger, do an update to the records, and in a before update trigger, do whatever changes you're doing. As this stands, it appears that you'll get a DML exception whenever the close date changes (recursive update to record already in a trigger). Your after insert trigger can be as simple as `update Trigger.new.deepClone(true);`

Comment: Based on your posted code, you appear to have a recursion issue. I don't know how your handler class knows the execution context or prevents the trigger from firing again once it's been fired in an execution context. See my answer.

Comment: @sfdcfox I don't get that error (possibly because of the SOQL queries? - I'm no expert). Could you please post the `update Trigger.new.deepClone(true);` as an answer in the context of the rest of my code. I've not used the deepClone *function* before so I'm not sure how that would change what I have already..

Comment: @crmprogdev I don't have a dedicated handler class, the `updateOpportunities()` method is called straight from the trigger without any other evaluation in between. Does that make sense or am I misunderstanding your terminology? To be honest, I don't know the difference between a *handler* class and any other types of class. As you can tell, I'm only just getting started with classes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can change your after-update trigger to a before-update trigger:

```
public class WE_OppUpdates {
    static Boolean recursiveUpdate = false;
    public static void recursiveInsert(Opportunity[] records) {
        recursiveUpdate = true;
        update records.deepClone(true);
    }
    public static void updateOpportunities(Opportunity[] oldRecords, Opportunity[] newRecords) {
        for(Integer index = 0, size = newRecords.size(); index < size; index++) {
            Opportunity oldRecord = oldRecords[index], newRecord = newRecords[index];
            if(recursiveUpdate || 
               oldRecord.CloseDate != newRecord.CloseDate || 
               oldRecord.Ramp_Profile__c != newRecord.Ramp_Profile__c) {
                   if(newRecord.Ramp_Profile__c == 'Immediate') {
                       // ...
                   } else if(newRecord.Ramp_Profile__c == 'Medium') {
                       // ...
                   }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And, of course, change your trigger as appropriate:

```
if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter) WE_OppUpdates.recursiveInsert(Trigger.new);
if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isBefore) WE_Updates.updateOpportunities(Trigger.old, Trigger.new);
```

After that, you'll find your code is easier to test, and recursion is a lot easier to control.

Comment: Just to check a couple of points - I can see from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm?search_text=deepclone0) the deepClone allows the preservation of Ids, time stamps & auto numbers which is good but does doing a clone like this impact related records at all? Also, is the purpose of the deepClone to avoid a DML statement and therefore not trigger an update or does it have a different application? Thanks.

Comment: @AlexS Related records aren't included in trigger context, so there's nothing to worry about there. The deepClone call is necessary because performing DML on Trigger.old, Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap, or any record within either of the collections, is forbidden. However, when you clone, you remove this internal flag that the DML statements use to determine if you're trying to perform an operation on those context records.

Comment: @AlexS My apologies. I forgot a return type (void). There may be a few other silly typos as well.

Comment: My first attempt's not looking too good, I've posted the complete class in [this](https://gist.github.com/aplssf/57681c4f78af3bc47731) Github Gist, along with the [trigger](https://gist.github.com/aplssf/0d7aa2ec27247e808b1e). I don't have code coverage from lines 33-71 and 88-135 in the class. I know that I'm asking for more than I should here but if you're able to take a look at a high level and make sure that the structure's not completely wrong (I'm not asking for help spotting errors line by line!), that would be huge help. I've never combined two sets of constructors in one class before.

Comment: @AlexS You're still constructing your class, while my demo was a static function, but you mixed that with the recursive insert call I suggested. Net result: 33-71 don't get executed because this is never called on insert, and 88-135 don't get called because we're now using static methods. Delete lines 18-74, then change your trigger in the Trigger.isBefore/Trigger.isUpdate path to call the static version of the function (lines 11-12). `WE_OppUpdates.updateOpportunities(Trigger.old, Trigger.new)` should do the trick.

Comment: @AlexS Although, full code coverage will need to cover various ramp profiles, so you may need to tweak your unit test to include all types of ramp profiles.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your code, it appears to me that when you insert new records in your test class, your trigger fires causing an update of Opportunity.

```
            if (Trigger.isInsert){

                ....

                for (Opportunity o : insertedOpps){

                        .....

                        } else if (o.Ramp_Profile__c == 'Standard'){
                            // set different values 
                        } 
                }
     // ==>     update oppsToUpdate;
```

When the above happens, this causes the trigger to fire again in the same execution context. Unless you add a boolean flag of some kind to prevent it, the trigger will fire again and do an after update in this execution context. When that happens, you'll see the same `trigger.old`as existed the first time the trigger fired in the `AfterInsert` context.

This happens **before** you ever do the update in your test class and may be what you're seeing in your debug logs. This same recursion will occur in your `AfterUpdate` handler code if you don't do something to prevent it.

More than anything, I recommend you add debug statements in your test class to obtain the values of your important variables after insertion of `Opportunities1` and following your query to get list `opportunities`. You'll also benefit from inserting debug statements in your code after `update opportunities;` (can be placed after `Test.stopTest();` if you prefer).

Once you have things sorted, your class should include assertions of what you expect those values to be instead of the debug statements following `Test.stopTest();`

Comment: Thanks, yes the Insert does cause the Trigger to fire & Execute the Update too. But I don't hit the recursion issue for some reason. I did try adding a boolean to stop that - it was changed from False to True after either Update and then checked in the alternative context but it didn't seem to have any effect..

Comment: Should the boolean be static and checked in my trigger or could I just include it in the class?

Comment: Where did you locate the boolean and is it static? Depending on the location, you may or may not want it to be static and you may need two of them, one for isInsert and one for isUpdate if located in your handler class. If in your trigger, you'd only need one to prevent re-entry. If in the class, don't use static, if in the trigger, you'll want to use static.

Comment: I'll update the post to show you a couple of options that I tried. At first, I tried a non-static boolean which had no effect, then I made it static but that stopped the class updating some of the records at all.

Comment: Locating it in the entry code of the trigger is preferable, in which case you can use static. If in the class, since there can be several instances, you won't want to use static as it could interfere with other instances of the class.

Comment: In the trigger is the approach that I hadn't tried. So I should set a static boolean to True (if it was first False) after each update dml statement and then check that boolean in the trigger before calling either method?

Comment: Not exactly. What you'll want to do is change `if (Trigger.IsAfter)` to `if (Trigger.IsAfter && !classname.booleanVarName)`, then immediately set `classname.booleanVarName = true;` That way code can't re-enter your trigger's `IsAfter` code section again in that execution context at all. Then it won't matter whether fired after insert or after update initially.

Comment: Great, I've done that and also added a public static boolean to my list of variables at the start of the class and then set that boolean to True from False, after each Update. I'm just going to run the test.

Comment: Hope it sorts your issues for you. I'll add that it wasn't clear to me how you were conveying the trigger context to your class of IsUpdate vs IsInsert, but figured that was code you'd not posted. That could be an issue for you as well if you've not taken care of it by some other means.

Comment: I haven't taken care of it at all if you could suggest a way for me to do that or point me in the direction of any resources, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: I will come back to you & accept the answer once I've finished testing. I'm just working through some unrelated issues with my test class.

Comment: Am surprised your code executes properly without that context. You can pass it to your class as a boolean variable. Dan Appleman covers it in his book Advanced Apex Programming. See this blog post for some guidance https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices.

Comment: Your solution does work, however there's a method that I call in the class (I didn't include it to keep the post clean) which populates a list of values that can only be retrieved in the Insert context &not in the Update context, once I've implemented the solution. I don't understand the issue because the method's being called outside the `Trigger.is` check. The only explanation that I can think of is there's one method in my test for Opportunity insertion & another for updates. But I don't see why that would matter. So I'll try sfdcfox's solution and see whether I have the same problem.

Comment: @AlexS Since "before insert" doesn't get called, you can also update those records in the recursiveInsert function I suggested before calling the update; that would let you do your initial insert lookups properly.